# Ionic 3 error adding plugin cordova geolocation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

When i add to my ionic project the cordova geolocation plugin, with this command:

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="To locate you"

i got this error:

BUILD FAILED

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Total time: 1.296 secs

Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-geolocation': Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone 
(D:\Usuarios.....\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)

at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)

at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)

at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)

at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESC... (exit code 1).

What´s happening??

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing plugin

> ionic cordova remove cordova-plugin-geolocation

and removing android platform

> ionic cordova remove platform android

so, adding the plugin again

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="To locate you"

and the android

> ionic cordova add platform android

Some bug in the way...